# ajax call to java spring controller is failing

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, controller, response

Here is my jquery script.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
script type="text/javascript" src="/**/resources/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="/**/showContract";
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert(url);         
        $.get(url,null, function (data,success) {
            alert("hi...");             
            //alert(data);
            //alert(success);               
       });
    });
 });
</script>
```

and my controller method..

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

@RequestMapping(value = "/showContract",method =RequestMethod.GET,produces="text/plain; charset=utf-8")     
@ResponseBody       
public String getContract() {
      System.out.println("j.ja.jajj");
      String message="oye ther";
      String message0[]={"hello","world"};
      return message;       
}
```

and my servlet-context

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->       

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

    <task:annotation-driven />

</beans:beans>
```

When I try to run it I am getting the following error

```html
2016 11:56:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse$ServletResponseHttpHeaders.getFirst(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:136)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:330)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I went through the forum for various answers.they all talk about how we should add `@Responsebody` annotation to the controller method so that the string will be returned.However in spite of doing this I am getting this error.The call is reaching the controller as  SOP outputs the string I have given. To my knowledge this error indicates that the response header is giving some issue, but I don't know why? I have annotated it and also mentioned the "produces='text/plain'".

Can anyone provide any clue on this?

some people had suggested to add

```html
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Which tomcat are you running this into? Is it through Eclipse? Post your pom.xml if you have one.

Comment: Hi,I am running it in eclipse with tomcat version v6.0. I am not using pom.xml.